# Use reflection to locate method calls

Tags: c#

I am working on a solution that will have a piece of code like this:

```
var result = this.ReaderFactory
    .Build<Arguments, Result>
    .Read(arguments)
```

Where `Arguments` and `Result` define a contract for a data access piece. The class that implements the data access is implemented in another assembly:

```
class Handler : IReader<SomeBusinessQuery.Arguments, SomeBusinessQuery.Result>
```

The `ReaderFactory` in the first fragment will find the Handler using reflection, execute the reader and return the result.

My question: is there some way to search through all compiled code to find the .Build statements? I would like to report whether exactly 1 handler exists for all such calls. I am interested in loading an assembly and analyzing it. I'm not interested in parsing code files prior to a build.

Comment: You could do this with Roslyn, if you're happy to use VS2015 Preview...

Comment: @Jon "I am interested in loading an assembly and analyzing it. I'm not interested in parsing code files prior to a build." - so kinda the opposite of Roslyn, no?

Comment: Mono.Cecil maybe? http://blog.aschommer.de/post/Analyzing-method-usage-with-Mono-Cecil.aspx ; or http://www.codethinked.com/static-method-interception-in-net-with-c-and-monocecil

Comment: As a side note: no amount of static analysis will reliably find reflection uses (or `dynamic`)

Comment: @MarcGravell: Doh, missed *just* the assembly being available. Was hoping it could be *part* of the build rather than *prior* to the build :) I think I may be a bit too focused on Roslyn now...